# DataBinding to List(Of CustomObject) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have been simple-binding the `Text` property of a `TextBox` for some time using a `DataTable` like so:

```
Dim dtbData As New DataTable

' populate table

Me.BindingSource.DataSource = dtbData
txtBox.DataBindings.Clear()
txtBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.BindingSource, "OrderNumber", True))

BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = Me.BindingSource
```

However, I am trying to change this to use a `List(Of CustomObject)` instead.  I am simply using the `dtbData` to populate the `List` and set the `DataSource` to the `List` instead.  I have set a breakpoint, and the `DataTable` and `List` are both populated.  If I comment out the line that adds the `Binding` to the `txtBox`, then the `BindingNavigator` works as expected, but if I leave it alone, the binding does not work.

Here is what I've tried:

```
Dim lstData As New List(Of CustomObject)
Dim dtbData As New DataTable

' populate table

For Each row As DataRow In dtbData.Rows
    Dim obj As New CustomObject

    obj.OrderNumber = CInt(row("OrderNumber"))
    lstData.Add(obj)
Next

Me.BindingSource.DataSource = lstData
txtBox.DataBindings.Clear()
txtBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", Me.BindingSource, "OrderNumber", True))

BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = Me.BindingSource
```

It seems like it should work the same.  Instead of a `DataTable`, the `BindingSource` is a `List(Of CustomObject)` though, so I'm not sure if I have to do something differently.  The property names being bound are still the same.  I have also tried `Me.BindingSource.Current` in the `Binding` but that doesn't work either.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

The `CustomObject` looks like so:

```
Public Class CustomObject
    Public OrderNumber As Integer
End Class
```

**EDIT**

I added a `Try`/`Catch` block around the binding, and I see the following error message:

**Cannot bind to the property or column OrderNumber on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember**

I just don't see what is different between binding to the `OrderNumber` column of a `DataTable` or the `OrderNumber` property of a `CustomObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what the problem was.  The `OrderNumber` wasn't defined as a `Property` of my `CustomObject`.  I changed the definition to this:

```
Public Class CustomObject
    Public Property OrderNumber As Integer
End Class
```

And now it allows me to bind the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to the `OrderNumber` property of my `CustomObject`.